# C# lambda (=>) syntax in F#

Tags: c#, syntax, lambda, f#, operator-overloading

Is it possible to define an => operator in F# so that it behaves like C#'s lambda syntax? This would allow one to write

```
x => y
```

instead of

```
fun x -> y
```

I'm an F# beginner, and my instinct tells me this isn't possible since `fun` looks like a special form.

Comment: fun is not optional in F# but for the case you've given ``fun x -> x`` which is the identity function you can use ``id``

Comment: Good point. I've updated the example so that readers don't think I'm only concerned about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because the lambda operator binds a variable (the left side is a variable, or any pattern matching, not an expression corresponding to a value), it's has special treatment by the parser.

Comment: Not to mention that C# doesn't compile without a *lot* more ceremony.